# Using Mongo Bson Serialization, how to create a proper deserializer with polymorphic data schema with not-standard field for discriminator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Created a dotnetfiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dUbJss

Given data that needs to be deserialized that is already written to hundreds of mongo databases:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId(aa),
    "shape": {
      "_bsonName": "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoRectangle",
      "geoJson": ...,
      "bottom": "1", "left": 2, "right": 3, "top": 4
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId(ab),
    "shape": {
      "_bsonName": "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoPolygon",
      "points": [[-79,36],[-80,37],[-79,38]]
  }
]
```

`[DiscriminatorValue]` can be one of:

- "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoEllipse" -> c# type "EllipseGeoShape"
- "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoRectangle" -> c# type "RectangleGeoShape"
- "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoPolygon" -> c# type "PolygonGeoShape"

```cs
public class Geofence
{
   public ObjectId Id { get;set; }
   [BsonElement("shape")]
   public GeofenceShape Shape { get; set; }
}
public class GeofenceShape
{
  [BsonElement("_bsonName")]
  public string BsonName { get; set; }
}
public class RectangleGeoShape : GeofenceShape
{
  public decimal Bottom { get; set; }
  public decimal Left { get; set; }
  public decimal Right { get; set; }
  public decimal Top { get; set; }
}
public class PolygonGeoShape : GeofenceShape
{
  public decimal[][] Points { get; set; }
}
```

Basically the _t field that mongo normally uses for discriminator needs to be "_bsonName" but I also have to read that _bsonName field and return our C# types: `RectangleShape|EllipseShape|PolygonShape`

So I created an IDiscriminatorConvention class

```
public class GeofenceShapeDiscriminatorConvention : IDiscriminatorConvention
{
    public string ElementName => "_bsonName";

    public Type GetActualType(IBsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType)
    {
        var bookmark = bsonReader.GetBookmark();

        string bsonName = null;
        bsonReader.ReadStartDocument();
        if(bsonReader.FindElement("_bsonName"))
        {
            bsonName = bsonReader.ReadString();
        }

        bsonReader.ReturnToBookmark(bookmark);

        switch (bsonName)
        {
            case "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoEllipse":
                return typeof(EllipseGeofenceShape);
            case "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoRectangle":
                return typeof(RectangleGeofenceShape);
            case "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoPolygon":
                return typeof(PolygonGeofenceShape);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Unexpected shape._bsonName of {bsonName}.");
        }
    }

    public BsonValue GetDiscriminator(Type nominalType, Type actualType)
    {
        switch(actualType)
        {
            case Type _ when actualType == typeof(EllipseGeofenceShape):
                return "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoEllipse";
            case Type _ when actualType == typeof(RectangleGeofenceShape):
                return "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoRectangle";
            case Type _ when actualType == typeof(PolygonGeofenceShape):
                return "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoPolygon";
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unexpected type '{actualType.FullName}' when serializing.");
        }
    }
}
```

unfortunately, this code fails with a StackOverflowException, where the Mongo code keeps calling GetActualType over and over and over again.

Looked through their source code, and theres not a lot of proper examples.

Of note, if I skip the `bsonReader.ReturnToBookmark(bookmark);` then I get a different error, basically `failed to GetBsonType() on a node of type value` (i forget the exact wording)

Comment: as I recall, by this line `bsonReader.ReturnToBookmark(bookmark);` you simply says that put "cursor" on the position where it was before your `GetActualType` method started, therefore it's valid reason to receive SO.

Comment: I also don't think that starting reading reader (ie stream) from `StartDocument` (ie from the root `{`) it's expected case. If you need example, I would look at implementations of `IDiscriminatorConvention` here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Conventions

Comment: Created a dotnetfiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dUbJss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a discriminator convention from scratch, you could derive one from `StandardDiscriminatorConvention` and use the `BsonDiscriminator` attributes, e.g.:

```
internal class GeofenceDiscriminatorConvention : StandardDiscriminatorConvention
{
    public GeofenceDiscriminatorConvention() : base("_bsonName")
    {
    }

    public static void Register()
    {
        BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(GeofenceShape), new GeofenceDiscriminatorConvention());
    }

    public override BsonValue GetDiscriminator(Type nominalType, Type actualType)
    {
        switch (actualType)
        {
            case Type _ when actualType == typeof(EllipseGeofenceShape):
                return "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoEllipse";
            case Type _ when actualType == typeof(RectangleGeofenceShape):
                return "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoRectangle";
            case Type _ when actualType == typeof(PolygonGeofenceShape):
                return "Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoPolygon";
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unexpected type '{actualType.FullName}' when serializing.");
        }
    }
}
```

On the `GeofenceShape` classes, you set the corresponding discriminator values like this:

```
// Base class
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(EllipseGeofenceShape), typeof(PolygonGeofenceShape), typeof(RectangleGeofenceShape))]
internal class GeofenceShape
{
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

// Derived class
[BsonDiscriminator("Company::Mapping::Geofences::GeoPolygon")]
internal class PolygonGeofenceShape : GeofenceShape
{
}
```

Comment: Your solution works in dotnetfiddle.  Thank you sir!  Now I have to figure out why it doesnt work in my project... lol